# System that manages real money

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project that incorporates real money into peoples accounts. Their accounts are stored in a MySQL database and inside it there is a column called "BALANCE".

When the users send money through PayPal, the PayPal api will do a callback to my server which will credit that users Balance with whatever they sent through PayPal.

The problem is, I plan on making the altering users balance part only accessible by my application. The way the balance is updated is by the URL just setting the method as a GET and setting the amount to whatever and it credits the balance.

I do not want people to just be able to visit that callback URL and keep updating their balance fraudulently.

What security would I be able to put in place that will only let legitimate balance changes occur?

Sorry if I didn't explain this too well. If anyone has questions, I'll try and explain it better. Thanks.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but this is one of those "if you need to ask, you shouldn't be building it" questions.

Comment: Have you actually looked at the PayPal documentation? I'm pretty sure if you look at the docs/example code when you receive a callback you're suppose to make a request to PayPal and verify the transaction.

Comment: Also: don't mutate data with GET calls.  That's just a bad idea for a lot of reasons.  From crawlers to caching to "people don't expect GET requests to change things"...

Answer (score 4):

I'll second Lucas's view that you should probably find someone more experienced than you to do this (you should find someone more experienced than me as well).  That said, I'll attempt to answer your question.

The PayPal API should provide a transaction ID or some other unique value.  Record that in your transaction log (you *do* have one, don't you?); if you see that value in a later transaction, you know the transaction isn't valid.  Record the invalid transaction in your audit log (you've got one of those as well, right?) and ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Security is like buying a safe. If you plan to keep things of real value inside (money, industry secrets, etc) then you invest in (probably multi-layer) security.

You described well one layer of security. The DB update is limited to the application. Still, what I one either gets the chance to execute code in space of your application, or intercepts the credentials, and using spoofing, makes the DB believe the request comes from the IP of the application?

Think of the following:

- are you operating like a bank? You may require bank license, and compliance to some Draconian (but very useful and full of sense) security rules.
- can people launder/anonymize money using your system? This may put you in conflict with international law, even if you are square with the local government.
- what happens if your database gets corrupted? Are you able to restore the transactions?
- what happens if customers are updating simultaneously their account? Do you initiate a transaction, or do you allow double spending of the funds?
- do you need 24/7 operations? How are you going to upgrade/maintain your MySQL DB?
- do you have employees? Do you have any mechanism to protect from insider threats?